# Neo4j Data Tidy Up - Removing Duplicates

Tags: neo4j, duplicates

I'm really enjoying Neo4j but I'm stuck on this small problem. My graph has Movie nodes, Actor nodes, Year nodes and Company nodes. Some movie nodes have been duplicated by accidental spelling mistakes. For example "Oceans Eleven" and "Ocean's Eleven" (notice the apostrophe).

[image]

So my question is, how do I duplicate all missing relationships from "Oceans Eleven" to "Ocean's Eleven" and then delete "Oceans Eleven"?

I need a script to run on a case by case basis. Don't worry about applying this too all movies with apostrophes because the spelling accidents are different.

--

Update with example data

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

Returns:

```
{"name":"Oceans Eleven","artwork":"oceans-eleven.jpg"}
{"name":"Brad Pitt","image":"brad-pitt.jpg"}
{"name":"George Clooney","image":"george-clooney.jpg"}
{"name":"Ocean's Eleven","artwork":"oceans-11.jpg"}
{"name":"2001"}
{"name":"Warner Brothers"}
{"name":"Matt Damon","image":"matt-damon.jpg"}
{"name":"Julia Roberts","image":"julia-roberts.jpg"}
{"name":"Netflix"}
{"name":"Andy Garcia","image":"andy-garcia.jpg"}
```

Comment: do you have data about which ones should be converted to what ?  like a csv file with two colums , with correct name and spelling mistake versions of them .

Comment: if the duplicates were formed because you ran some cleaning process like removing special characters on movies . Then we can perform same cleaning process on the movie names in graph and try to find duplicates

Comment: we have text search in graph but you can't be 100% certain that the results will be correct .

Comment: I need a script to run on a case by case basis. Don't worry about applying this too all movies with apostrophes because the spelling accidents are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've managed to merge duplicate Neo4j nodes together is like this.

```
MATCH (fake:Production {name:"Oceans Eleven"})-[out]->(outNodes)
WITH outNodes, out
OPTIONAL MATCH (real:Production {name:"Ocean's Eleven"})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(real, type(out), properties(out), outNodes) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

First copy the outbound relationships.

```
MATCH (fake:Production {name:"Oceans Eleven"})<-[in]-(inNodes)
WITH inNodes, in
OPTIONAL MATCH (real:Production {name:"Ocean's Eleven"})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(inNodes, type(in), properties(in), real) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Then copy the inbound relationships.

```
MATCH (real:Production {name:"Ocean's Eleven"})-[r]-(b)
WITH real, b, TAIL (COLLECT (r)) as rr
FOREACH (r IN rr | DELETE r)
```

Delete any newly created duplicate relationships.

```
MATCH (fake:Production {name:"Oceans Eleven"})
DETACH DELETE fake
```

And finally, delete the duplicate node.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (duplicateNode:Movie{name:"Oceans Eleven"})-[r]->(destNode)
WITH destNode , r  
OPTIONAL MATCH (trueNode:Movie{name:"Ocean's Eleven"})-[r1]->(destNode)
WHERE r1<>r 
WITH r1,r,destNode,trueNode
WITH r,trueNode,destNode, CASE r1 WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END AS lst 
UNWIND lst as x
CALL apoc.create.relationship(trueNode,type(r),properties(r), destNode)
YIELD from,to 
RETURN from,to LIMIT 100
```

the above query will create all the outward relations.

```
MATCH (duplicateNode:Movie{name:"Oceans Eleven"})<-[r]-(destNode)
WITH destNode , r  
OPTIONAL MATCH (trueNode:Movie{name:"Ocean's Eleven"})<-[r1]-(destNode)
WHERE r1<>r 
WITH r1,r,destNode,trueNode
WITH r,trueNode,destNode, CASE r1 WHEN NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS lst 
UNWIND lst as x
CALL apoc.create.relationship(destNode,type(r),properties(r), trueNode)
YIELD from,to 
RETURN from,to LIMIT 100
```

this will do the inward relations ..
after running the above two for each mistake .
you can do the following to delete all the incorrect nodes

```
MATCH (movie:Movie) WHERE movie.name IN ["Oceans Eleven","..",".."] 
DETACH DELETE movie
```

incase if duplicate node relations are completely distinct from the relations the original node has, then you can ignore the following part in the above scripts ,

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (trueNode:Movie{name:"Ocean's Eleven"})-[r1]->(destNode)
WHERE r1<>r 
WITH r1,r,destNode,trueNode
WITH r,trueNode,destNode, CASE r1 WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END AS lst 
UNWIND lst as x
```

and just Match the trueNode

```
MATCH (trueNode:Movie{name:"Ocean's Eleven"})
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the first part. I think it doesn't like the word CASE. Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 6, column 28 (offset: 226))
"WITH r,trueNode,destNode CASE r1 WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END AS lst "

Comment: sorry , need to add a comma after descNode ..updated my answer

Comment: I'm getting another error when I run the first part. Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 8, column 1 (offset: 288))
"CALL apoc.create.relationship(trueNode,type(r),properties(r), destNode)"

Comment: And after adding a RETURN to the end and installing apoc, I get this error: Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 8, column 1 (offset: 296))
"CALL apoc.create.relationship(trueNode,type(r),properties(r), destNode)"

Comment: I'm still struggling with this I'm afraid.

Comment: hi david ,updated my answer , had to yield output from apoc procedure and return them .

Comment: I'm still getting an error I'm afraid: Unknown procedure output: `from` (line 9, column 7)